# Tableau - compare average quantity before and after variable date

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataset containing client names, license codes, billing dates, and billing quantity. What I need to do is analyze average quantity before and after a specific date. How I find that particular date per client is by looking for specific billing codes and returning the minimum date in that subset of data. I have attached a sample of the data.

For example, I need to find the minimum date for each name where the Billing code begins in “E”. For “Allen” this date would be August 2015. For “Ama” is would be May 2015. I then want to compare the average monthly quantity for those codes NOT beginning with “E” before the minimum date, and the average monthly quantity for those codes that do begin with “E” following that minimum date. For example, “Allen” would show approximately 50 units on average before August 2015 and approximately 78 units on average after August 2015, inclusive. “Ama” would show 19 and 24, respectively.

Ideally I would like to run a regression of the average quantities for each firm.

```
NAME|BILLING DATE|BILLING CODE|QUANTITY
----|------------|------------|--------
Allen|Jan-15|A11|64
Allen|Feb-15|A11|64
Allen|Mar-15|A11|64
Allen|Apr-15|A11|64
Allen|May-15|A11|65
Allen|Jun-15|A11|1
Allen|Jul-15|A11|1
Allen|Aug-15|A11|1
Allen|Sep-15|A11|1
Allen|Oct-15|A11|1
Allen|Nov-15|A11|1
Allen|Dec-15|A11|1
Allen|Jan-16|A11|1
Allen|Feb-16|A11|1
Allen|Mar-16|A11|1
Allen|Apr-16|A11|1
Allen|May-16|A11|1
Allen|Jun-16|A11|1
Allen|Jul-16|A11|1
Allen|Aug-16|A11|1
Allen|Jan-15|A22|4
Allen|Feb-15|A22|4
Allen|Mar-15|A22|4
Allen|Apr-15|A22|4
Allen|May-15|A22|4
Allen|Jun-15|A22|4
Allen|Jul-15|A22|4
Allen|Aug-15|A22|4
Allen|Aug-15|E11|38
Allen|Sep-15|E11|36
Allen|Oct-15|E11|40
Allen|Nov-15|E11|40
Allen|Dec-15|E11|40
Allen|Jan-16|E11|40
Allen|Feb-16|E11|40
Allen|Mar-16|E11|38
Allen|Apr-16|E11|38
Allen|May-16|E11|40
Allen|Jun-16|E11|40
Allen|Jul-16|E11|40
Allen|Aug-16|E11|39
Allen|Oct-15|E22|40
Allen|Nov-15|E22|40
Allen|Dec-15|E22|40
Allen|Jan-16|E22|40
Allen|Feb-16|E22|40
Allen|Mar-16|E22|38
Allen|Apr-16|E22|38
Allen|May-16|E22|40
Allen|Jun-16|E22|40
Allen|Jul-16|E22|40
Allen|Aug-16|E22|40
Ama|Jan-15|A11|21
Ama|Feb-15|A11|20
Ama|Mar-15|A11|20
Ama|Apr-15|A11|20
Ama|May-15|A11|20
Ama|Jun-15|A11|20
Ama|Jul-15|A11|20
Ama|Aug-15|A11|20
Ama|Sep-15|A11|18
Ama|Oct-15|A11|18
Ama|Nov-15|A11|18
Ama|Dec-15|A11|18
Ama|Jan-16|A11|18
Ama|Feb-16|A11|18
Ama|Mar-16|A11|18
Ama|Apr-16|A11|18
Ama|May-16|E11|24
Ama|Jun-16|E11|24
Ama|Jul-16|E11|28
Ama|Aug-16|E11|21
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create a LOD calc that determines the cutoff date per client. Say start with a fixed LOD calc. See the docs on LOD calcs. For example, define Cutoff_Date as:

```
{ fixed Name : min(if startswith([Billing Code], "E") then [Billing Date] end) }
```

Then write a pair of calculated fields that return the quantity if the date is before (after) the cutoff date or null otherwise. Hint, in an if statement without an else clause, the default implicit else condition returns null.

For example, define Quantity_Before_Cutoff as:

```
if [Billing Date] < [Cutoff_Date] then [Quantity] end
```

and define Quantity_After_Cutoff similarly -- deciding which calculation should include quantities that were billed on the cutoff date.

Finally, you can use your 2 new measures as desired to calculate avg quantities before and after the cutoff date.

For your regression model, you might also want a Boolean valued calculated field that indicates whether a record is before or after the cutoff. Make it a dimension instead of a measure